# What light switch is this? No longer works after 4 new aaa batteries

Tags: walls, light, battery

Was asked to replace the batteries in this light switch with new ones but now the switch no longer turns the light on or off. Can someone help me identify what light switch I have or tell me why it no longer functions?[image]

Comment: did you replace the batteries because they were flat or is it possible the switch is somehow broken?

Comment: Does the receiver also have batteries?

Comment: It appears to be a smart switch of sorts, what brand/model #?

Comment: Assuming the new batteries are good, and assuming they are installed correctly (you checked, right?) I think you need to look at the manufacturer's instructions. If you can't find that information on the parts you can see, you may have to dismount it from the wall and check the back.

Comment: (looks like a surface-mount radio switch, which may or may not be "smart".)

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to find that specific "wireless wall switch" but by using those terms found quite a few results. Consistent across many/most of these results is that the kit includes a receiver device.

The light you expect to operate should have this module within the housing. If that module has failed or become disconnected, your fresh-battery transmitter will not function as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your battery contacts are green with corrosion. I wouldn't expect it to work. Suggest throw away, get new switch. If that's not practical, you could try sanding the cr*p off the terminals and maybe they'll work again (for a while...) Vinegar and a Q-tip also can help get the crud off.